# Suitability of ANTLR for parsing and creating routing rules

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I need to build a custom rule builder and I'm wondering whether ANTLR4 would be an appropriate choice to build a parser if I could figure out the grammar. The grammar, I imagine would be something similar to a SQL WHERE clause.

Our API would need to accept and return some sort of compact expression to/from the UI like this (I'm calling this the wire format for now):

```
"(&(day-of-week='Monday")(|(manufacturer='Honda')(manufacturer='BMW')))"
```

The UI should be able to transform this compact expression into some expression-tree like data structure from which a UI could be built, such as:

```
and
left
  day-of-week
  equals
  Monday
right
  or
  left
    manufacturer
    equals
    honda
  right
    manufacturer
    equals
    BMW
```

and the reverse should also be true - I should be able to take this structure and turn it into the compact form so I can hand it back the the API.

I know that ANTLR can generate parsers in JavaScript and in C#, so will ANTLR be able to generate a JavaScript parser that can take the wire format expression and create a JavaScript expression tree, and also take the wire format and generate a C# expression tree?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: Btw, you really don't want to create 2 grammars: 1 to parse the wire format, and 1 to parse the expression-tree like data structure. The latter is simply a representation of your parse tree, there is no need to parse it.